# ios - button not responding to click after I change its coordinates

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a button that I configure like this in my .h file:

```
- (IBAction)addBusiness:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *planBusinessButton;
```

then I do this in my .m file:

```
- (IBAction)addBusiness:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Plan business clicked 1");
}

- (IBAction)planBusinessButton:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Plan business clicked 1");
}
```

but in my onLoad I do something like this:

```
CGPoint pt = planBusinessButton.center;
    pt.y -= 275;
    planBusinessButton.center = pt;
```

The problem is that the button click is not firing in the IBAction when I click the button.

Would the changing of the location of the button have an effect on why the button is not getting clicked?

Why would the button click not fire in the IBAction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Moving the button should not affect it's action firing, unless it's moved off the view or being below some other view that would intercept the tap.

If tap is not firing the button, check that:

- IB connections are properly connected
- methods exist in the proper location
- button is enabled for user interaction

Try to avoid doing any view modifications in viewDidLoad method, as the view is not ready yet...
instead, try setting the button center in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Just moved the code there...same problem that the button does not respond to clicks.

Comment: so in this case, check that all connections are in place and button is configured properly. Sometimes it's best to start over (delete and add a new button and set it up from scratch)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly. Gesture Recognizers could be handling the events in the location the button moved to or there could be another view blocking the button at the new location and you need to bring the button to the front. Also, you should put this into viewDidAppear or an IBAction if you want an event to trigger it.

Comment: I just clicked to where the button was and nothing happened there either.

Comment: could be another view blocking the button.  I had a UITextView where the button got moved to that I hid like this:  self.businessList.hidden=TRUE;

Comment: How should I hide the UITextView so that it does not interfere with the button?

Comment: If it's hidden it should be fine except you should be using YES instead of TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your planBusinessButton.frame is not outside its super.frame . 
eg:if the button`s frame like this (0,-200,100,200), when the button added to its super view it will not handle the click event.

Comment: I can see the button on the screen, and none of it is off the screen - is that what you mean?

Comment: yes , if your button added to the main screen , when it is not off the screen,it will work, but if your button added to a view which frame eg:(0,200,100,200),the button will not work although it not off the screen

Comment: not sure I understand.  The button was on the screen. But on the bottom of it...but visible.  Then I moved it up towards the top.  Is that ok? :)

Comment: i mean when you do "planBusinessButton.center = pt;"please make sure the button frame is not off the view`s frame which view [view addSubviews:planBusinessButton]